# Using gunicorn to run app error

Tags: python, linux, django, wsgi, gunicorn

I have gunicorn successfully installed

Every time I run this command:

```
$ gunicorn hello.wsgi:application --bind example.com:8001
```

I get this error:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
[ERROR] Invalid address: ('example.com', 8001)
```

I am following this tutorial:

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: lol i realize how dumb that was but then again i have not slept for 1 day

Comment: ;) +1 for honesty and the useful link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`example.com` is just an example domain. Use `0.0.0.0:8001` as bind address instead.

```
gunicorn hello.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Comment: its says no module named hello.wsgi,when i use 0.0.0.0 im new to django is this suppose to be a file in the app directoy?

Comment: @user3149525, Try the command in parent directory of the app directory.

Comment: Just to add to this.  This doesn't look for a file named "hello.wsgi", it is using the dot namespace to look for a file named "wsgi.py" inside the "hello" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Let's look:

First we have the 'public_html' folder for the web sites, then we have the virtualenv folder apps 'mysite'

Then, in 'mysite' you have 'myapp' Django, inside that there are another 'myapp' folder with the wsgy.py file.

So inside your django app first folder you run:

gunicorn myapp.wsgi:application --bind site.com:8001